# Vue 3 - global axios instance

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I want to make an `axios` instance available globally in my Vue 3 app.

Setup:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
})

const app = createApp()

app.config.globalProperties.$axios = axiosInstance

app.mount(el)
```

Usage:

```js
let response = await this.$axios.get('/api/leads')
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: this.$axios.get is not a function
```

Seems like `this.$axios` is `undefined`. I cannot figure out why.

Notes:

1. I'm using the `@vue/compat` build of Vue to migrate from Vue 2 to Vue 3. I'm following the [official migration guide](https://github.com/vuejs/core/tree/main/packages/vue-compat#overview).
2. When inspecting `this.$axios` - I get `ƒ wrap() ...`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is caused by a [known bug](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4403), where function properties (the result of `axios.create()` is actually a function) are bound to the component instance proxy, which inadvertently hides the function's own attached properties (i.e., `$axios.get` in this case). The [PR that fixes the issue](https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/4873) has not yet been merged.

A workaround is to convert the `axiosInstance` (a function) into an object with the spread operator:

```js
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
})

const app = createApp()
                                        
app.config.globalProperties.$axios = { ...axiosInstance }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-compat-axios-global-prop?file=src/main.js)